# SQL query execution differs each and every time in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, query-performance

I have used below query to fetch maximum of 6000 records in SQL Server 2012.

```
Select A.Date, A.City
From dbo.TBL_Auction (NoLock) A
Inner Join dbo.TBL_PLACE (NoLock) B On A.Place_Fk_Id = B.Place_Pk_Id
Inner Join dbo.TBL_SALES (NoLock) C On A.AucCode = C.AucCode
Inner Join dbo.TBL_SERVICES (NoLock) D On C.AucCode = D.Servicecode And C.Regno = D.ServiceRegno
Inner Join dbo.TBL_REGISTRATION E On Left(D.ServiceId,12) = E.REGNO 
Where C.Status = 'L' And E.Status = 'L'
```

But query execution time sometimes takes above 4 minutes and sometimes within 2 seconds. I have created indexes in all the joining tables. But no luck.

In last three tables over 200k records are there. I have checked execution plan. In execution plan, Clustered Index Scan is used instead of Seek. I have created indexes for all columns in joining tables. In development environment, when more number of developers accessing database, at that time query takes more time.

How to boost up query execution time?

Comment: Do you have an execution plan to see if the index(es) are used? How many rows are there in the tables? Structure of the tables? Indexes? Also take into account that when the data is already in memory the execution time is much, much faster then when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Why "date" and "city" doesn't have alias "a" ? it belongs to TBL.Auction table ?
Don't you have some diferent types between the tables that are joined ?
have you see the execution plan for Registration Table ? .. Join with function "left" could be a problem

Comment: Date And City belong to Auction Table. I have one doubt. I have tested above query single user environment in SSMS. At that time the query runs fast (Execution time:1 seconds). When multiple user environment accessing same database the query takes more than 4 minutes. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Pedro said, the LEFT() function may result in performance problems with row-by-row evaluations and index or table scans. I have experienced this and so have many others. See http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/sql-server-functions-dragging-query/ and https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/ .